# Printing Multiple Images In C#

Tags: c#, printing

I am currently writing an app that allows users to look at a large group of images and rearrange them with the mouse(ala Windows Table). Everything works great, but i am trying to setup a system where I can select multiple images and send them to the printer.

I can easily do this my iterating over the list of selected objects, and then pop out of the printer just fine. The problem I am having is trying to combine them into 1 single print job, rather than individual jobs for every page. The main reason is so a print preview is available. When i iterate my list in the print preview, it only shows the me first image, and no other pages appear. I've tried e.HasMorePages, but i still end up with the same result. Here's the code i have in my print event:

```
    private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (PictureBox PrintPic in SelectedCollection)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(PrintPic.Image, 0, 0);
            PageCounter++;
            e.HasMorePages = (PageCounter != SelectedCollection.Count);
        }  
    }
    private void pd_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
    {
            PageCounter = 0;
    }
```

I'm still new to C# coding, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the loop:

```
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(SelectedCollection[PageCounter], 0, 0);
  PageCounter++;
  e.HasMorePages = (PageCounter != SelectedCollection.Count);
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! I knew i was right on track, but I wouldn't have thought to simply call the images right out of the collection. Thanks!